# File Pointer keeps printing out wrong data when I run the program C Programming

Tags: c, struct, switch-statement, token, file-pointer

I'm in the process of developing a read inventory function. I want it to read the content in a inventory.txt file that I have placed in a project with multiple files. When I run it, I get the first integar value for the product number for all the products, but after the product number I get corruptted data that doesn't match my text file. Looks like the error is now in my switch statements. Does anyone see anything wrong how I'm trying to pull the data from the text file in my swith statements? For example my console output looks like this:

```
1000 1.49 3.79 10 A Fish Food


/* Here's my structure, I have this stored in a header file. */ 
struct inventory_s
{
    int productNumber;
    float mfrPrice;
    float retailPrice;
    int numInStock;
    char liveInv;
    char productName[PRODUCTNAME_SZ];
}; 

/* Here's the text I'm trying to insert from the inventory.txt file (this is my input file*/

1000, 1.49, 3.79, 10, 0, Fish Food
2000, 0.29, 1.59, 100, 1, Angelfish
2001, 0.09, 0.79, 200, 1, Guppy
5000, 2.40, 5.95, 10, 0, Dog Collar Large
6000, 49.99, 129.99, 3, 1, Dalmation Puppy

/* Here's the function I've built so far */

int readInventory(void)
{
    int count = 0; //counts record
    int length = 0; //shows length of string after its read
    int tokenNumber = 0; //shows which token its currently being worked on
    char* token; //token returned by strtok function
    struct inventory_s newInventory; //customer record
    int sz = sizeof(struct inventory_s) * 2; //string size to read
    char str[sz]; //where data is stored

    FILE* inventoryFile = fopen("customer.txt", "r"); //opens and reads file
    if (inventoryFile == NULL) //if file is empty
        {
            printf("Could not open data file\n");
            return -1;
        }
    while (fgets(str, sz, inventoryFile) != NULL) //if file is not empty
    {
        tokenNumber = INVENTORY_FIELD_PRODUCTNUMBER;
        length = strlen(str);
        str[length - 1] = '\0';
        token = strtok(str, ","); //adds space when there is a "," and breaks into individual words
        while (token != NULL)
        {
            switch (tokenNumber)
            {
                case INVENTORY_FIELD_PRODUCTNUMBER:
                    newInventory.productNumber = atoi(token);
                    break;
                case INVENTORY_FIELD_MFRPRICE:
                    newInventory.mfrPrice = atof(token);
                    break;
                case INVENTORY_FIELD_RETAILPRICE:
                    newInventory.retailPrice = atof(token);
                    break;
                case INVENTORY_FIELD_NUMINSTOCK:
                    newInventory.numInStock = atoi(token);
                    break;
                case INVENTORY_FIELD_LIVEINV:
                   (newInventory.liveInv, token);
                   break;
                case INVENTORY_FIELD_PRODUCTNAME:
                   strcpy(newInventory.productName, token);
                   break;
            }
            token = strtok(NULL, ",");
            tokenNumber++; //starts the next inventory

         }
        count++;
        printf("%i %.2f %.2f %i %c %s\n", newInventory.productNumber, newInventory.mfrPrice, newInventory.retailPrice, newInventory.numInStock, newInventory.liveInv, newInventory.productName); //prints out in console


    }
    fclose(inventoryFile);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `strcpy(newInventory.liveInv, token)` - `liveInv` is a plain `char`, not an array of `char`, so you can't `strcpy()` into it. Also you attempt to `printf()` the entire line after reading every token, instead of after you've read all the tokens in that line. You're missing a closing brace somewhere in your code. You don't show us your input file.

Comment: I'm working on it. Thanks for helping me out. I'm getting further and further each time. Now I can get it to print out , but only one line of the text file prints out.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define INVENTORY_FIELD_PRODUCTNUMBER  1
#define INVENTORY_FIELD_MFRPRICE       2
#define INVENTORY_FIELD_RETAILPRICE    3
#define INVENTORY_FIELD_NUMINSTOCK     4
#define INVENTORY_FIELD_LIVEINV        5
#define INVENTORY_FIELD_PRODUCTNAME    6

//defines the sizes of the contents in the structure
#define PRODUCTNAME_SZ 20

int main()
{
    struct inventory_s
    {
        int productNumber;
        float mfrPrice;
        float retailPrice;
        int numInStock;
        char liveInv;
        char productName[PRODUCTNAME_SZ];
    };

    int count = 0; //counts record
    int length = 0; //shows length of string after its read
    int tokenNumber = 0; //shows which token its currently being worked on
    char* token; //token returned by strtok function
    struct inventory_s newInventory; //customer record
    int sz = sizeof(struct inventory_s) * 2; //string size to read
    char str[sz]; //where data is stored

    FILE* inventoryFile = fopen("inventory.txt", "r"); //opens and reads file
    if (inventoryFile == NULL) //if file is empty
        {
            printf("Could not open data file\n");
            return -1;
        }
     while (fgets(str, sz, inventoryFile) != NULL) //if file is not empty
    {
        tokenNumber = INVENTORY_FIELD_PRODUCTNUMBER;
        length = strlen(str);
        str[length - 1] = '\0';
        token = strtok(str, ","); //adds space when there is a "," and breaks into individual words

        while (token != NULL)
        {
             switch (tokenNumber)
             {
                case INVENTORY_FIELD_PRODUCTNUMBER:
                    newInventory.productNumber = atoi(token);
                    break;
                case INVENTORY_FIELD_MFRPRICE:
                    newInventory.mfrPrice = atof(token);
                    break;
                case INVENTORY_FIELD_RETAILPRICE:
                    newInventory.retailPrice = atof(token);
                    break;
                case INVENTORY_FIELD_NUMINSTOCK:
                    newInventory.numInStock = atoi(token);
                    break;
                case INVENTORY_FIELD_LIVEINV:
                  (newInventory.liveInv, token);
                   break;
                case INVENTORY_FIELD_PRODUCTNAME:
                   strcpy(newInventory.productName, token);
                   break;
            }
            token = strtok(NULL, ",");
            tokenNumber++; //starts the next inventory

        }

        printf("%i %.2f %.2f %i %c %s\n", newInventory.productNumber, newInventory.mfrPrice, newInventory.retailPrice, newInventory.numInStock, newInventory.liveInv, newInventory.productName); //prints out in console
        count++;

    }
    fclose(inventoryFile);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Figured it out! I had the fclose() closing the file before it could read the next line of input. Thanks for everyones help in assistting me in figuring it out.